# responsive layout in older browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my layout. I tried to create a simple, responsive two column layout. It's quite difficult because I want to combine constant and percentage width.

The working layout code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #leftBar {
            width: 20px;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            background: red;
        }

        #topBar {
            width: calc(100% - 20px);
            height: 30px;
            float: left;
            background: green;
        }

        #map {
            width: calc(100% - 20px);
            height: calc(100% - 30px);
            float: left;
            background: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="leftBar"></div>
    <div id="topBar"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I create the same layout that will work in older browsers?

Comment: What browsers are you having trouble with? The only thing I see potentially limiting here is the use of calc(), but there are other ways to achieve your effect, such as using margins, to deal with the 20 - 30px offset

Comment: As You wrote calc function is the limitation. I would have layout compatible with IE8.

Comment: Like I said, use something else then, like margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolute layout and the **top, right, left and bottom property**.
Here's an example matching to your site (I could not find out the sense of #map so, now it is an responsive content box):

```
#body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#leftBar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#topBar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
}

#map {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This would fix the calc() problem, the other properties should work in any Browser...